# How to create an html table with Jade iterating an array

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm starting with node expressjs framework and I came across this problem I can't solve.

I'm trying to display a table with some blog posts (yes, a blog...) but I don't get it done.

This is the Jade template code:

```
div
  table
    thead
      tr: th Posts
    tbody
      each post, i in userPosts
        tr(class=(i % 2 == 0) ? 'odd' : 'even'): a(href='/admin/post/' + post.id) #{post.author} - #{post.title}
```

And this is the HTML output:

```
<div>
  <a href="/admin/post/1">Post 1</a>
  <a href="/admin/post/2">Post 2</a>
  <a href="/admin/post/3">Post 3</a>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Posts</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="odd"></tr>
      <tr class="even"></tr>
      <tr class="odd"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

So, any ideas?

Comment: Check out n-th child CSS rules.  You don't need to compute even/odd and manually add a class. http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I was using an existing design I dindn't want to change. Anyway, that's not the problem. I already tried to print a classless tr tag and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found that the problem was that I was missing the TD tag for each TR.
So the jade code should be like this:

```
div
  table
    thead
      tr: th Posts
    tbody
      each post, i in userPosts
        tr
          td 
            a(href='/admin/post/' + post.id) #{post.author} - #{post.title}
```

Comment: I had to remove the i, and do each post in userPosts

Comment: what is the meaning of : next to tr?

Comment: What is the problem in this code. Not making tr for td below th tr.

.col-md-12
       
      
      table.table.table-bordered.table-hover
        thead
          tr
            th No.
            th Title
            th Description
            th Operations        
- let i=1;
      each task in tasks
        tbody
          tr
            td #{i++}
            td  #{task.title} 
            td  #{task.description} 
            td           
                a(class=`${task.status==true ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-dark'}`, href=`/turn/${task._id}`) Done

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
div
  table
    thead
      tr: th Posts
    tbody
      each post, i in userPosts
        tr(class=(i % 2 == 0) ? 'odd' : 'even') 
          td
            a(href='/admin/post/' + post.id) #{post.author} - #{post.title}
```

Comment: I already tried that one. It doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the meaning of : next to tr?

Answer (score 1):

With current pug version didn't work for me. Instead I modified the code to the following pattern:

```
div
  table
    thead
      tr
        th title...
    tbody
      each post in userPosts
        tr
          td= post.author
          td= post.title
```