# nodejs : jade table - with Dynamic json from controller

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I have a simple nodejs program, where I am retrieving the data from mongodb using Mongoose and wanted to display it as a table using jade. Here is my code:

**Server side code**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  //Query the user table
  user.find(function(err, result){
      res.render('index',{users: JSON.stringify(result)});   
  });
});
```

**Jade code**

```
div
  form(action='/',method='post')
    div(data-role='fieldcontain')
      fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
        label(for='name') User Name
           input(id='name',type='text',value='',placeholder='Type your username here',name='name')
    div(data-role='fieldcontain')
      fieldset(data-type='vertical', data-role='controlgroup')                                           
       label(for='fname') First Name
           input(id='fname',type='text',value='',placeholder='Type your first name here',name='fname')
    div(data-role='fieldcontain')
      fieldset(data-type='vertical', data-role='controlgroup')                                           
       label(for='lname') Last Name
           input(id='lname',type='text',value='',placeholder='Type your last name here',name='lname')
     div(data-role='fieldcontain')   
      input(type='submit',value='Create Profile',data-transition='fade', data-theme='c')
- var userlist = {users}
div
 table
  thead
   tr: th Users
    tbody
     each user in userlist
      tr
       td=user
```

And my **model** looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var user = new Schema({
    username: String,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', user);
```

The issue is that the message from the route to jade is not read by jade as JSON. I tried printing #{users} and it prints the result in full. However, in the each loop, its not able to separate out the two records.

I have a look at the questions:

[Jade static anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961655/jade-static-anchor-link-with-dynamic-link-data-from-server-side)

[Jade iterating an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921556/how-to-create-an-html-table-with-jade-iterating-an-array)

[HTML Table in Jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187290/how-rotate-html-table-using-jade-template-node-express-jade)

Somehow, I feel that the message is not received as JSON and hence the issue. Please can you help?

Comment: what is the need of using `JSON.stringify(result)` here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code without JSON.Stringify its running fine .

Assuming you have record(s) for user in your database.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

   User.find(function(err,result){

     console.log(result);
     res.render('index', { title: 'Express' , users: result });
   });
});
```

here is the code in index.jade

```
extends layout

block content
 h1= title
 p Welcome to #{title}
 -var userlist = users
 div
   table.table.table-hover
    thead
      tr: th Users
    tbody
      each user in users
        tr
          td=user.firstname
          td=user.lastname
          td=user.username
```

when i started my server and hit the index page i got the following result.

[image]

But when i did the same thing with JSON.stringyfy() didn't get anything displayed here but data is there.

Hope it helps!! Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create automatically your headers without specifying the fields:

**Server side code**

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    user
        .find({})
        .select('-_id -__v') // This removes hidden MongoDB fields
        .lean() // This removes all mongoose fields and return a simple javascript object
        .then(result => { // I'm using promises, but you can use callbacks as well
            console.log(result);
            res.render('index', { title: 'Express', users: result });
        })
        .catch(ex => console.log(ex));
});
```

**Jade code**

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}

  -var firstUser = users[0] || undefined;
  if firstUser
    div
      h1 Users
      table.table.table-hover
        thead
          tr
            each value, key in firstUser
              th=key
        tbody
          each user in users
            tr
              each value, key in user
                td=value
```